# Find the probability that a randomly selected student walks to school.

Tags: probability, statistics

It is given that: A survey was taken during school to see how students get to school. The data was summarized in the table below-

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8euT0.png)

What's confusing is that the question contains the different ways to get to school as well as the different genders. The different genders are what get me confused because the more varieties, the harder it is to find the probability.

If the question was more like "What is the probability of someone (meaning any gender) walking to school?" Basically putting the genders together would make the question a whole lot easier. Say if there were 50 boys and 50 girls, they could just say 100 students instead of separating them...

I did notice however after rereading the question, that they asked for a randomly selected student rather than a certain gender, so I tried adding up the males and females that walked to school which gave me 42+36=78. I then added up the other males and females which gave me 85+77+30+47+44+39=322

I don't think what I tried was correct though because when I tried dividing the answers I just got the decimal 0.24223602484

Just to make sure I tried converting this decimal to a percentage which gave me 24.22360248%, but that is not one of the answer choices.

Answer Choices:

A. 9%
B. 10.5%
C. 13.25%
D. 19.5%
E. 21%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would be D here’s the work I did my guess is that you messed up when adding everything together https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0susi2xdaa

Answer (score 2):

To get the probability that a randomly selected student walks to school, you must divide the number of students walking to school ($42+36=78$) by the total number of students ($85+77+30+47+42+36+44+39=400$), not just by the number of other students. This gives $19.5\%$.